# MongoDB throwing timeout exception after 1636 inserts

Tags: java, mongodb, exception, timeout

so I came across with this problem with Mongo: I have a java program that inserts documents into Mongo, the data is extracted from a java object called 'Article', this is it's structure simplified without getters, setters, equals, etc:

```
public class Article {

    private String title;
    private String doi;
    private String country;
    private String date;
    private ArrayList<String> authors;
    private ArrayList<String> references;
}
```

The code I use for the insertion is this:

```
public static void saveArticle(Article article) {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("bibliometricDB");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("papers");        

    Document doc = new Document("doi",article.getDoi())
        .append("date", article.getDate())
        .append("title", article.getTitle())
        .append("country", article.getCountry())
        .append("authors", article.getAuthors())
        .append("references", article.getReferences());
        collection.insertOne(doc);
    }
}
```

My **main** method iterates through a big set of articles (more than 100.000) and calls this "saveArticle(Article)" for each one. Article's data is correct (because I check it previously for every article), if not, the article is discarded.

**HERE IS THE WEIRD PART**: Every time I run this program and starts processing the articles, when the insertion number 1637 comes, Mongo throws the following error (regardless of the article):

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:94)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:198)
```

I'm really stuck with this error. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Okey, just found out what the problem was, I forgot to add 'mongoClient.close()' so it fails eventually.

Comment: Some comments: you only should connect to MongoDB *once*, and reuse the connection. The Java MongoDB client comes with automatic connection pooling. Second, for operations involving a large number of documents, you should use [bulk operations](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/), especially for inserts. However, you should call `.execute()` every some 10k operations to prevent excessive use of RAM.

Comment: Last but not least, for the data model I see, I wonder if you weren’t better off with a graph database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take account of your comments.